# Determinant of coefficient matrix of cyclic system

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, determinant

I was working on the following problem (#284) from the book "Putnam and Beyond" (2017):

> Solve the system of equations for $x_1, \ldots, x_{100}$: $x_i + x_{i+1} + x_{i+2} = 0$ for $1\le i\le 100$. (Indices wrap around cyclically.)

I solved it (finding the solution $x_i = 0$ for all $i$) by summing all the equations and subtracting the 33 necessary equations to find any given variable.

However, I was wondering if I could apply Cramer's Rule to this system. In order to do so, I would need to demonstrate that the determinant of the coefficient matrix is nonzero.

I used Wolfram|Alpha to compute the generalized determinant $\det A_n$, where $A_n(i,j) = 1$ if $j - i = 0, 1, 2$ and $0$ otherwise, and I noticed that $\det A_n$ seems to always equal $3$. (Example for $n=5$: [link.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=determinant%20of%20%7B%7B1%2C1%2C1%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C1%2C1%2C1%7D%2C%7B1%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C1%7D%2C%7B1%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C1%7D%7D))

Can someone explain how to prove this observation? The only potential approach I see is to generalize $A_n$ to be a function of a variable $x$ (perhaps replacing $1$s along the diagonal), factor it, and evaluate it again. Are there general techniques for such determinants?

Comment: Can you check the determinant for $n = 3, 6$?

Comment: Based on tests for $3\leq n\leq 24$, it seems that the determinant is $0$ if $3|n$ and $3$ otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Let $C_n$ be the cyclic group of order $n$, generated by $t$.  Let $\mathbb{Z}[C_n]$ be the group ring.  We have a commutative diagram, where each row is a short exact sequence of $\mathbb{Z}[C_n]$ modules:

\begin{eqnarray*}\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
0&\to& I &\to &\mathbb{Z}[C_n] &\stackrel\epsilon\to &\mathbb{Z}&\to&0\\
&&g\downarrow\,\,\,&&\downarrow f&&\,\,\,\,\,\downarrow3\\
0&\to& I &\to &\mathbb{Z}[C_n] &\stackrel\epsilon\to &\mathbb{Z}&\to&0
\end{array}
\end{eqnarray*}
where $f$ is multiplication by $1+t+t^2$.  Then the determinant you are looking for is: $${\rm Det}_\mathbb{Z}(f)=3{\rm Det}_\mathbb{Z}(g)$$

Here $I$ is the augmentation ideal and is generated by $1-t$ over $\mathbb{Z}[C_n]$ and $\epsilon$ is the augmentation map, sending $1\mapsto 1$.

Suppose $n=3k$.  Then \begin{eqnarray*}&\,\,&g((1-t)(1+t^3+t^6+\cdots +t^{3(k-1)}))\\&=&(1+t+t^2)(1-t)(1+t^3+t^6+\cdots +t^{3(k-1)})=0,\end{eqnarray*}
so $g$ has non-trivial kernel and ${\rm Det}_\mathbb{Z}(g)=0$, so your determinant is $0$.

On the other hand, if $n\neq 3k$ for any integer $k$, then we may pick $r$ such that $3r\equiv 1\mod n$.

Then:
\begin{eqnarray*}&\,\,&g((1-t)(1+t^3+t^6+\cdots +t^{3(r-1)}))\\&=&(1+t+t^2)(1-t)(1+t^3+t^6+\cdots +t^{3(r-1)})=1-t.\end{eqnarray*}
Thus $g$ is surjective and must have determinant $\pm1$, so your determinant is $\pm3$.

Comment: You could probably write this argument out in simple linear algebra terms, by taking the basis $(1111\cdots11)$, $(1-1000\cdots00)$, $(01-1000\cdots00)$,....